# In app/code/User/Customdata/Block/Adminhtml/User/Edit/Tab I have create 3 more php file in this tab

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminform

In `app/code/User/Customdata/Block/Adminhtml/User/Edit/Tab` I have create 3 more php file in this tab.

I want to call all file in Main.php file in edit form in Admin. but file is called and data also showing but when we submit form data then only one Main file data post. I want to 2 more files data post with that data.
Note: 3 file data coming from 3 different tables.

If i put all in single file then
how to setform data

```
$form->setValues($model->getData());
$form->setValues($models->getData());
$this->setForm($form);
```

here only last (`$form->setValues($models->getData());`) data set. but i want to set both these

```
 $form->setValues($model->getData());


$form->setValues($models->getData());
```

Comment: You should load each model separately and set values from each model

Comment: Can you please share how to load each model separately. it's already there.$form->setValues($model->getData());

    $form->setValues($models->getData());

    $this->setForm($form);

Comment: show me antities from all your 2 tables and how you get $model variable

Comment: in layout file I removed extra code
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Abc\Customdta\Block\Adminhtml\Abc\Edit" name="customedta_abc_edit"/>
 <block class="Abc\Customdta\Block\Adminhtml\Abc\Edit\Tab\Maininvestorinfo" name="customedta_abc_edit_tab_maininvestorinfo"/>
             <block class="Abc\Customdta\Block\Adminhtml\Abc\Edit\Mainfunds" name="customedta_abc_edit_tab_mainfunds"/>
<block class="Abc\Customdta\Block\Adminhtml\Abc\Edit\Mainincomes" name="customedta_abc_edit_tab_mainicomes"/>

Comment: it is for Maininvestorinfo >>>    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('expert');

           it is for Mainfunds >>>    $models = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('funds');

             it is for Mainincomes >>>    $modelss = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('incomes');

             when post form data only Maininvestorinfo is post. I want to 2 more on save buttion